# Getting Tomcat user in Java

Tags: tomcat

is there a way to get the logged in user name (and group) from a Tomcat system. I read something about configuring Tomcat, so it is getting the user information out of a database. But I found now information about getting the name of the user (in my GWT Project), which is logged in.

I'm trying to write a little GWT project and would like to publish the user name to the front page.

Thx for your help.

Comment: Is Tomcat handling the authentication for your application?  That is, did you set up a realm in your configuration file?

Answer (score 9):

You can try these two methods from the HttpServletRequest interface.

`getUserPrincipal()` returns a Principal from which you can get the logged used as `getUserPrincipal().getName()`.

`isUserInRole("Administrators")` returns true if the current Principal is in the provided role.

Of course this only works if you are using tomcat realm authentication found [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html).

Answer (score 0):

getUserPrincipal().getName()

There's a typo in above answer.