# j_security_check need user name to populate form from database

Tags: java, j-security-check

I am working on a homework assignment that is due shortly and I have searched and searched and searched for the answer to this and I just don't know where to go at this point.

I am using Eclipse Juno, with Tomcat 7.0 and a MySql database. I have to develop a web application for a pizza place. I have pretty much everything working so will only post the code here if requested since there is a ton.

My problem is I have a login form that calls the j_security_check, which works just fine. However, when the user is logged in they are taken to a customer form which is supposed to display their name, address, phone number and give them the option of editing any of it or just starting their order. My problem is I need to get the j_username and pull the customer information from my database to populate the form when the user is redirected from the login page to the customer.jsp page. We are not supposed to use <% ----- %> in our code if we can help it and to keep that in servlets. I just am lost on how to get that j_username and then call a servlet to populate the form (I can do the population if I can get the data).

HELP PLEASE!!! I know I am missing something really simple here and it is driving me nuts.

Ok I have tried the demo you sent and actually found another demo with the FORM like my project. I still cannot get it to work. I am a little lost. When I do the demo exactly as they have it the servlet generates text and outputs it. I was able to change it to a requestDispatcher and send it to the page I need it to go to on the login. The demo just has it going to the url host.../YourProject/test not an actual page. I am lost on how to get it to call the servlet so I can grab the header information with my project. I have the servlet LoginUser I want the user to login on login.jsp and there is a login_error.jsp in case of an error. When the user successfully log's in they should be taken to customer.jsp and the fields on the page populated with their data. I need to change this to use SSL too but haven't got there yet I am still trying to get the data for the customer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244622/getting-tomcat-user-in-java

Comment: I am using a JDBCRealm for the login.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're using is basic authentication in Tomcat.  Check out [this post for instructions.](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html) In summary, you'll need to grab the authentication header from the servlet request and parse it to grab the username (first you'll likely need to base64 decode it).  Then you can use that username to look up the necessary information in the database.